# oAuth Asp.net Core 2.0 Web Api: machine-to-machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0

I'm working in a Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web Api and one of the controllers is a customer CRUD using the [Quickbooks API](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_online/5_api_reference/00_overview). To be able to connect to this API I have to be authenticated via oAuth 2. I cannot ask the user to authenticate via his account on quickbooks, this integration should be invisible to anyone consuming this API.

My Question is: how can I do this machine-to-machine authentication using oAuth 2 on Asp.net core 2.0?

I have the client id and secret. I even made a call that actually returns me a bearer token, but when I try to use this token their API returns error 500, which makes me think that what I did to get the token is just wrong. Code below:

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyy", ParameterType.RequestBody);            
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

This is the response: `{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"eyJlbmMiOixxx","expires_in":3600}`
But as I told, this token seems to be invalid.

Can you help me? Links, comments, anything would be useful.

Comment: How are you sending the bearer token? Also, before doing this in .NET have you tried doing this in PostMan or something alike?

Comment: In the header. Yes, using the token generated by their oAuth test it works when making the request: https://developer.intuit.com/v2/ui#/playground . I understand the flow of oauth the problem is that I cannot show the quickbooks authorization screen to the users using the app, it has to be invisible

Comment: Try putting fiddler in the middle and check what exactly is your .NET application posting to intuit.

Comment: Have you checked the app permission (aka Application Scopes ?) Maybe you don not have granted any permission to the client app. Decode the token (is a JWT token, see on line and check scopes). Try to use postman with Bearer Token and see if return an explain error.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do machine-to-machine. So I did a page where the main user has to authorize at least once. Since I couldn't find any help on Intuit community, I'm posting it so it can be useful to someone else.

In the `Startup.cs`, method `ConfigureServices` :

```
    services                
        .AddOAuth("QuickBooks", options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["QuickBooks:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["QuickBooks:ClientSecret"];
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/QuickBooks/Authorize");

            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["QuickBooks:AuthorizationEndpoint"];
            options.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["QuickBooks:TokenEndpoint"];
            options.UserInformationEndpoint = Configuration["QuickBooks:UserInformationEndpoint"];

            options.Scope.Add("com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting");
            options.Scope.Add("com.intuit.quickbooks.payment");

            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuickbooksAuthSettings>(context.TokenResponse.Response.ToString());
                    resp.AuthorizationCode = context.Request.Query["code"].ToString();
                    resp.RealmId = context.Request.Query["realmId"].ToString();
                    TimeSpan tsAccessToken;
                    if (TimeSpan.TryParse(resp.AccessTokenExpireStr, out tsAccessToken))
                        resp.AccessTokenExpire = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(tsAccessToken);

                    resp.RefreshTokenExpire = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt64(resp.RefreshTokenExpireStr));

                    var opts = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
                    opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                    var qbService = new QuickBooksService(this.Configuration, new AppDbContext(opts.Options));
                    qbService.SaveToken(resp);
                }
            };
        });
```